# Optics proof: Beam expander telescope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, telescopes

**Beam expanders** are afocal optical devices that widen/narrow the diameter of an incoming laser beam $D' = D / M$.

**Telescopes** are afocal optical devices that multiply angle of incidence of each light-ray by a magnification factor $\theta' = \theta\cdot M$.

Interestingly, both are fundamentally equivalent: one can use a telescope as a beam expander and vice versa. The picture includes some examples of their internals.

> For both of these configurations and also 3-lens afocal systems,
> I have noticed a ([well-know](https://www.edmundoptics.eu/knowledge-center/application-notes/lasers/beam-expanders/)) relation between the **angular magnification**
> of the telescope and the **narrowing of the light-beam**:
> $$
> \text{angular magnification}\equiv \left|\frac{\theta'}{\theta}\right| = \frac{1}{\text{ratio of beam diameter expansion}} \equiv \frac{D}{D'} $$
>
> Why are they even related? How could I prove this holds for **every** afocal system?

[image: Afocal system examples]

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially conservation of etendue. Etendue ($G$) is the product of area ($A$) and solid angle ($\Omega$):

$$ G = A\Omega$$

In an optical system etendue can be increased but cannot be decreased. For the types of systems you are asking about, etendue is constant. This is true no matter how many lenses (or mirrors) you use.

Solid angle is proportional to $\sin^2\theta$, or in the small angle limit proportional to $\theta^2$ and area is proportional to $D^2$. To conserve etendue these must satisfy the relationship you presented (in the limit of small angles).

> How could I prove this holds for every afocal system?

Its certainly not true of *every* afocal system. You can introduce scattering, or aberrations. Or if you try to make the beam too small you will hit the diffraction limit. Or you could go out of your way to violate what most people would think of as a reasonable design. But for the types of systems you are probably thinking about, this should always hold.

Comment: Thank you, never heard of it. I believe this is indeed the way to go :) i still have to figure out the small details tho...